# Can I integrate Xbox Live login into my site?

Tags: live, xbox360

Some game developer sites are using Xbox Live for authenticating their users ([example](http://forzamotorsport.net/)). Basically something similar to OpenID concept. I wonder is there any api I can use to put this xbox login to my site or it is only for Microsoft partners?

Comment: I've seen it on an iPhone app too. Worse case scenario - could your scrape the details of the official Xbox site?

Comment: Looking at the site, they seem to login with Windows Live ID

Comment: Xbox live and windows live are integrated probably, but when you login there your xbox gamertag is displayed, so it is not just windows live account.

Comment: @alex: I don't need details, I just want to identify users using their xbox gamertags instead of asking to register on my site.

Comment: Also, for the guys answering this thing, how about PSN?

Comment: Anyone can help I solved this till getting the Microsoft email just  missing the Xbox Gamertag in Response

Answer (score 1):

You maybe wanna check out http://www.xboxlivenation.com they say to have developed an web API for XBL but their website has broken links to the sources, maybe if you lurk more in the forums...

Answer (score 1):

A Xbox interest group named "Team OpenXbox" has released a set of libraries to authenticate on Xbox Live Services on GitHub ([Link](https://github.com/OpenXbox))

Currently available are libraries for C## and Python.

Remark: I have not been able to test the library yet but will in the short-term future.

Answer (score 1):

Xbox Live has APIs you can use:

https://github.com/Microsoft/xbox-live-api/tree/master/InProgressSamples/Social/Xbox/C